# What is the best practice to rollback a SQL script in AWS RDS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-rds, rollback

I'm studying AWS and trying to get a mental picture of the process for a SQL rollback. Let's say I've got a containerized front-end and middle tier deployment + a SQL script that deploys several new stored procedures, modifies a few stored procedures, drops a column in TableX, adds a constraint on TableY, inserts several records to TableZ, etc. A boatload of changes. On Day 1 the front-end and middle tier containers are deployed and the SQL script is applied. All looks good for a few days as clients start working with the updates. Then it's realized on Day 5 that we need to roll things back to pre-Day 1. No problem on the front-end and middle tier deployments as we can just deploy the prior containers. However, we can't just restore the database as it has 4 days of client changes to the data. In this case, does AWS offer a service that can "undo" Day 1's SQL deployment without wiping out all of the clients' subsequent data changes? Or are we still just making sure we have a custom rollback SQL script prepared to return the db objects to their pre-Day 1 state as in years past?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to somehting like this is to try to make sure that a major rollback doesn't get to your production platform (so gets picked up in dev or staging first). QA and integration testing is your friend.

That said, life doesn't always work out the way you want. So for a major structure change like this (that would need you to retain data entered after the change) an approach I've used with success in the past is to have a mirrored script that undoes the changes in full (as far as possible). You may end up with synthetic data when it comes to restoring a dropped column, but it should get you back to where you started.

Oh, and it goes without saying that you should version everything: table structure, stored procedures etc. It makes isolating and backing out changes a whole lot easier.